# I tried to get the title and description by youtube v2 API, is it deprecated?

Tags: youtube-api

I tried to getting the title and description using
"gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/r59xYe3Vyks?alt=json&v=2"

I can get only the link in both the title and description 
Example :"title":{"$t":"https://youtube.com/devicesupport"}, $description":{"$t":"https://youtube.com/devicesupport\nhttp://m.youtube.com","type":"plain"},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v2 API is deprecated since March 4, 2014. Use [v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=r59xYe3Vyks&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
200 OK 
- Show headers -  
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"krboRo_tpL036O3XTWYvMqtyDRY/fK282W1_39vDbymuMqWnJvwrkQE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"krboRo_tpL036O3XTWYvMqtyDRY/U1E3J7lGHCn99RoPUJcPQEOsXpw\"",
   "id": "r59xYe3Vyks",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-14T20:57:48.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCs6nmQViDpUw0nuIx9c_WvA",
    "title": "Java Tutorial For Beginners 1 - Introduction and Installing the java (JDK) Step by Step Tutorial",
    "description": "java read line from stdin\njava examples for beginners\njava beginners tutorial\nmit java programmieren\njava online tutorial\ncompiler java\nJava (Beginner) Programming Tutorials\nJava For Beginners \nThe Java™ Tutorials \nWelcome - Learn Java - Free Interactive Java Tutorial\nLearn Java Programming - Learn To Code Java Like a Pro\u200e\nJava Tutorial For Beginners: Learn Java Programming From\njava programmieren lernen\njava kurs\nSearches related to java programming for beginners\njava programming for beginners pdf\njava programming for beginners pdf free download\njava programming examples\njava programming for dummies\njava programming tutorial\njava programming for beginners using eclipse\njava programming for beginners book\njava programming for beginners ebook",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r59xYe3Vyks/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r59xYe3Vyks/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r59xYe3Vyks/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "ProgrammingKnowledge",
    "categoryId": "27",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Java Tutorial For Beginners 1 - Introduction and Installing the java (JDK) Step by Step Tutorial",
     "description": "java read line from stdin\njava examples for beginners\njava beginners tutorial\nmit java programmieren\njava online tutorial\ncompiler java\nJava (Beginner) Programming Tutorials\nJava For Beginners \nThe Java™ Tutorials \nWelcome - Learn Java - Free Interactive Java Tutorial\nLearn Java Programming - Learn To Code Java Like a Pro\u200e\nJava Tutorial For Beginners: Learn Java Programming From\njava programmieren lernen\njava kurs\nSearches related to java programming for beginners\njava programming for beginners pdf\njava programming for beginners pdf free download\njava programming examples\njava programming for dummies\njava programming tutorial\njava programming for beginners using eclipse\njava programming for beginners book\njava programming for beginners ebook"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```